# Draw Rectangle Over Buffered Image Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, graphics2d

I have a `JPanel` on which I draw the image of a map using a `BufferedImage`. I also have a button which, when clicked will highlight a part of the map by drawing a red rectangle over that part.

However, when I zoom in on the image, the rectangle stays where it was before. I assume the reason behind this is that the rectangle is being drawn over the panel and over the Image.

Is there a way to adjust the rectangle's position in accordance with the zoom?

Here's how I draw the rectangle and the image:

```
//the variable years[activeIndex] is an array which stores my Buffered Images
  Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g.create();
  g.drawImage( years[activeIndex],0, 0,(int)width,(int)height,null);
  g2.setColor(Color.red);
  g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
  g2.drawRect(this.getWidth()/2,this.getHeight()/2, 20, 20);
  MapViewer.imagePanel.revalidate();
```

[This is the rectangle when there is no zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIlfN.jpg)

[This is the rectangle with the zoom, it stays in its place because its on the JPanel and not on the BufferedImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKBxQ.png)

Comment: How do you scale the image? Is the rectangle always at the center - it's position (center of the panel) seems to be fixed, as well as it's size.

Comment: I'm scaling the image by increasing the size of the JPanel in which the image resides and then setting the image size equal to the size of the JPanel. The size of the rectangle should be fixed. It's position should be fixed too, but not on the JPanel. I want to fix the rectangle over the image so whenever the image is zoomed the rectangle stays at the same point of the image. Hope that's enough information and thanks for your response